# How to use autocomplete typeahead with X-editable?

Tags: python, django, autocomplete, typeahead, typeahead.js

I need to use typeahead with x-editable in Django app. My source is remote ajax function.
html:

```
  <div class="controls">
    <a href="#" id="industry" data-type="typeahead" data-title="Input industry">
      {% if init_dict.industry %}{{ init_dict.industry }}{% else %}Enter industry {% endif %}</a>
  </div>
```

script:

```
$('#industry').editable({
  params: { 'csrfmiddlewaretoken': csrf},
  type: 'text',
  title: 'Enter industry',
  url: '/companyHouse/editable/pending/company/industry/',
  pk: {{ init_dict.pending_company_pk }},
  source: ['/companyHouse/query/tag/?query=%QUERY'],
  items: 8,
  value: '{{ init_dict.industry }}'
});
```

The error I get is one of local, prefetch, or remote is required
Any help is appreciated!